# Using Web Deploy to synchronize web application files

Tags: iis, webdeploy, web-farm, microsoft-web-deploy, web-farm-framework

We develop a website that our customer is using internally, we host the application in 3 - 10 windows servers for them. If we want to modify the content of our application, we are forced to access all the servers manually and deploy in all of them. We have decided to deploy the files to one location that will be accessible without needing our customer's internal network access(we've asked them to setup a DMZ) and from there synchronize the contents to all servers.

From just browsing through, I've come across IIS Web Farms and Web Deploy which does something similar to this, my question is, we want the deployment so happen to all servers one by one, or all at once and on demand. Is it possible to configure WebFarms/Web Deploy to work like this? Also if synchronize fails, restoring backups, pulling reports. Is this all doable with Web Deploy/WebFarms?

Comment: Microsoft only ships very basic operations in them, so if you want things like "the deployment so happen to all servers one by one, or all at once and on demand" and "if synchronize fails, restoring backups, pulling reports", you have to write your own code/scripts upon them.

Comment: I understand that not all features will be available out of the package. Is it possible to write code for doing the tasks that I need? Or is using rysnc a better way to go?

Comment: I doubt rsync is ever a good way. Asking about possibility is always an interesting question. Why cannot it be possible?